# Where does SharePoint save uploaded files on the system?

Tags: sharepoint

I have uploaded a doc file on SharePoint site. Now I want to know the path of the file on the server (System).

Comment: I've added the "sharepoint" tag to your question. Consider the use of any other relevant tags and, maybe, you will receive more appropriate answers. Don't forget many users on SO considers only highlighted questions (that is tagged questions with one they put in their "interested tag" list).

Answer (score 6):

If you uploaded it into a SharePoint document library, then it's not on the filesystem.  It's in a SharePoint content database.  If you can elaborate on what you want to do with the file, it will be easier to recommend ways to attack the problem and get the info you need.

Answer (score 2):

It is saved in the content database. That's why you can't find it on disk.